# How to see the before and after snapshot of the changed document in Firestore?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

###### Scenario

I am using `onSnapshot()` to listen to document changes in Firestore. My document contains an array field. I would like to see which items were added/deleted from the nested array in the document. Is there any way to achieve this?

###### Possible Solution

I see there is an `oldDocuments()` field in the `QuerySnapshot.snapshot` object which could be used to achieve my goal. I could just compare the `oldDocument` with the returned snapshot to see what changed in the nested array. The problem is `oldDocument` is a private field that I can't access through the API.

I am using Android Kotlin as my client.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing built in that can help you see what exactly in a document has changed. However, there are two workarounds.

The first one would be to attach a persistent listener and [view changes between snapshots](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#view_changes_between_snapshots). That means that when you attach the listener you get a list of all documents your query returns. As soon as a document is changed, onEvent will fire. This means that you'll be able to know the document that has changed. Knowing that you already have a list with the initial documents, you can find the old document based on the ID and compare it against the new one.

Another solution would be to save a new document each time something changes. This is some kind of document versioning. In this way, you'll always be able to check the new document against the old one using only two document reads.